# Trying to build Google Sitemap feed and it's downloading instead of displaying in browser

Tags: rss, google-xml-sitemaps

As the title mentions, I'm trying to build a Google News sitemap feed and whenever I go to the /news-sitemap route it downloads a text file.

I've tried feed types, "RSS, rss2, and rss-http," suggested in the docs, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/feed_content_type/, but it's still downloading. Not sure what I'm missing. Below is a snippet where I'm defining the urlset and the content type.

Thank you.

```
<?php

header( 'Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type( 'rss-http' ) . '; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), true );
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . esc_html( get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) . '"?' . '>';

?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
```

Comment: Have you looked into using a plugin for that? For example, there is a plugin specifically for this: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/xml-sitemap-feed/

Comment: Do browsers normally show XML sitemap feeds? I wouldn’t be surprised if they don’t know how to deal with them and just download.  Can you find another one that works the way you’re expecting and compare the full headers sent?

Comment: @Lisa, thank you for the response. I did look into that but it looks like it would involve uninstalling the one that's currently being used and that's a no-go. Fortunately, it looks like it may have been a local instance issue and when I moved it further upstream the problem wasn't there anymore.

Comment: @Rup it's mainly for the Google web crawlers, not really for anyone to be able to view on the site.